# How to make discrete colormap contiguous in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

How to convert discrete colormap to contiguous one in matplotlib? I need something like this:

```
import matplotlib.colors as colors
cm_d = colormap = colors.ListedColormap(["#ffffff", "#ffcdcd", "#ff989b", "#ff6669", "#ff1818", "#d20000", "#a30002", "#720001", "#500002", "#670061", "#5e1a8b", "#3d0064", "#555555", "#343434", "#000000"])
cm_c = do_some_magic(cm_d)
```

*Discrete colormap (cm_d):*
[image: Discrete colormap]

*Contiguous colormap (cm_c):*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a continuous colormap
you want to call this method:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list

> Static method; factory function for generating a smoothly-varying LinearSegmentedColormap.